# Why was there no swine flu in our universe in Supernatural The French Mistake?

Tags: supernatural

In The French Mistake, Sam does some research into the history of our universe and finds that none of the apocalyptic events that look place in Season 5 in his universe, occurred in ours. However, I'm slightly confused at swine flu. Apparently this was created by Pestilence as part of his plan to spread the croatoan virus through the vaccine. But swine flu also took place in the universe of Jared Padalecki and Jensen Ackles (our universe), so why didn't Sam see anything about swine flu?

Perhaps Pestilence didn't actually created swine flu, or the universe in the French Mistake wasn't precisely ours, since that wasn't Jared Padalecki's house.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer:  It's not our universe, just *really close*.

Remember this?

Well, [Eric Kripke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Kripke) isn't actually dead.

Answer (score 1):

Sam was looking for evidence of *apocalyptic* events -- events that would have been world ending, or nearly so. He also knew the specifics of the events in question, and was looking for things that matched.

In this case, the swine flu part of Pestilence's plan is probably not what Sam would be looking for. That's a naturally occurring disease, which breaks out every so often. Indeed, as you pointed out, there really was a 2009 swine flu pandemic -- but there had been at least a half-dozen major outbreaks before that. The earliest recorded swine flu outbreak was in 1918.

What *didn't* happen, though, was an outbreak of the *Croatoan* virus as a result of the vaccination. It's also very likely that the big drug company distributing the infected vaccines (which was run by a demon) didn't exist. (I see no evidence of a company called Niveus Pharmaceuticals; there is a Niveus Medical but they're not a drug company, they make devices to treat bone and muscle disorders). Without those extra details, Sam would probably have written this off a just another naturally occurring epidemic.

Answer (score 0):

In the episode does it actually say Pestilence created swine flu, or that he is just causing outbreaks of it? Because he could really cause any disease or illness he wanted and use one that already exists as a way to propagate out the croatoan virus through the vaccine. 
Although if it does say he actually created swine flu, then it was probably just the writers being forgetful, or as you said it wasn't actually our universe.